# predict.gbm, $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a section of R code that I wrote for a project I am working on. I would like to shorten the code to save space in my project. I am relatively new to R and don’t have a lot of experience with `for` statements or functions like `apply`, but I have been reading the R help files as well as other questions on this site, and r-bloggers.com to try and get some sort of a basic understanding of these functions.

The functions I am using are taken from page 18 of the dismo vignette "[Boosted Regression Trees for ecological modelling](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/brt.pdf)".

My goal is to...

1. repeat the `gbm.fixed` function for every level of `tree.complexity` from 1 to 5 and every level of `learning.rate` from 0.001 to 0.01 by 0.001.
2. repeat the `predict.gbm` function for all of the `gbm.fixed` results.
3. return all of the `calc.deviance` results to a matrix where the column names are something like `tc1lr001:tc5lr01` so I can plot the results.

My approach was to use `for` loops. I was able to to run all of the `gbm.fixed` functions by using the following code...

```
for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in seq(0.001,0.01,0.001)){
    #Call the gbm.fixed model
    assign(paste0("test.tc",i,"lr.",substr(j,3,7)),
           gbm.fixed(data=data.train,
                     gbm.x = 3:10,
                     gbm.y = 2,
                     learning.rate = j,
                     tree.complexity = i,
                     n.trees = 10000))     
  }}
```

However, when I try to run the `predict.gbm` function using the following code...

```
for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in seq(0.001,0.01,0.001)){
    tree.list<-seq(100,10000,100)
    assign(paste("pred.tc",i,"lr.",substr(j,3,7),sep=""),
           predict.gbm(paste0("test.tc",i,"lr.",substr(j,3,7)), 
                              data.test, 
                              n.trees=tree.list, 
                              "response"))
  }}
```

...I get the following error...

```
Error in object$Terms : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I did some reading, and there are quite a few posts regarding `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`, but I couldn't find any that seemed to have the same application as what I am doing.

I am sure this is something simple, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it right now. Any input is appreciated.

For reference, here is an example of one iteration (tree.complexity=1, and learning.rate=0.001) of the working code I am trying to loop.

```
samp <- sample(nrow(data), round(samp.size * nrow(data)))
data.train <- data[samp,]
data.test <- data[-samp,]

tree.list<seq(100,20000,100)
test.tc1.lr001<- gbm.fixed(data=data.train, 
                               gbm.x=2:10,   #predictor variables
                               gbm.y=1,      #response variable
                               learning.rate=0.001,
                               tree.complexity=1,
                               n.trees=20000)

pred.tc1.lr001 <- predict.gbm(test.tc1.lr001, 
                                  data.test, 
                                  n.trees=tree.list, 
                                  "response")

#Calculate the deviance for all the results
pred.dev.tc1.lr001 <- rep(0,200)
for (i in 1:200) {
pred.dev.tc1.lr001[i] <- calc.deviance(data.test[,1],
                                             pred.tc1.lr001[,i], 
                                             calc.mean=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Try putting `browser()` in your last `for` loop and try debugging (or settings the `i` and `j` values manually). Your code is not working for me as I don't have access to your `data`. Here's a line of code to think about: `test <- c(name1 = 1, name2 = 2, name3 = 3);test$name1`.

Comment: You can also use `traceback()` to see which line threw the error. But, as Roman pointed out, evaluating each object in turn will show you where you've created an `atomic vector` when you need a `list` object to be able to use the `$` operator.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik and Carl Witthoft Thanks for your comments! If I am able to find a solution I will post an answer to my question.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? (I have a similar problem)